# Создание формы обратной связи с php обработчиком

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! У меня есть файл forma.html в нем содержится тело формы + php обработчик mail.php + css файл screen.css. При заполнении формы и нажатию кнопки "Отправить" вылазиет ошибка. Пожалуйста помогите, не знаю в чем ошибка. Спасибо.
Файл

```
forma.html
    <head>
        <title>Форма</title>    
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=windows-1251" />    
        <meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/screen.css" media="screen" />
    </head>
    <body>    
    <div id="container">    
            <h1>Форма обратной связи</h1>                   
            <form id="form1" action="mail.php" method="post">           
                <fieldset><legend>Контактная форма</legend>
                    <p class="first">
                        <label for="name">Ваше имя</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" />
                    </p>
                    <p>
                    <label for="email">Ваш Email</label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="30" />
                    </p>
                    <p>
                    <label for="tel">Ваш телефон</label>
                    <input type="text" name="tel" id="tel" size="30" />
                    </p>            
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>                                          <p>
                    <label for="mess">Сообщение</label>
                    <textarea name="mess" id="mess" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
                   </p>                             
                </fieldset>    
            <p class="submit"><button type="submit">Отправить</button></p>  
            </form>   
    </div>    
    </body>
    </html>

Файл mail.php

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
     <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
     <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251"/>
     <title>Обратная связь</title>
     </head>
     <body>
     <?php
     if (isset($_POST['name'])) {$name = $_POST['name'];}
     if (isset($_POST['email'])) {$email = $_POST['email'];}
     if (isset($_POST['mess'])) {$mess = $_POST['mess'];}
     if (empty($name))
     {
     echo "<b>Не указано имя!<p>";
     echo "<a href=contacts.html>Вернуться к заполнению формы</a>";
     exit;
     } 
     if (empty($email))
     {
     echo "<b>Не указан e-mail!<p>";
     echo "<a href=contacts.html>Вернуться к заполнению формы</a>";
     exit;
     }
     if (empty($mess))
     {
     echo "<b>Сообщение не написано!<p>";
     echo "<a href=contacts.html>Вернуться к заполнению формы</a>";
     exit;
     }
     $to = "моя почта@ya.ru";
     $headers = "Content-type: text/plain; charset = windows-1251";
     $subject = "Сообщение с вашего сайта";
     $message = "Имя пославшего: $name \nЭлектронный адрес: $email \nСообщение: $mess";
     $send = mail ($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
     if ($send == 'true')
     {
     echo "<b>Спасибо за отправку вашего сообщения!<p>";
     echo "<a href=index.html>Нажмите,</a> чтобы вернуться на главную страницу";
     }
     else 
     {
     echo "<p><b>Ошибка. Сообщение не отправлено!";
     }
     ?>
     </body>
     </html>

Файл css

    @charset "utf-8";

    body{ 
        background:#f8f8f8;
        font:13px Trebuchet MS, Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
        color:#333;
        line-height:160%;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        text-align:center;
        }

    h1{
        font-size:200%;
        font-weight:normal;
        }       
    h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{
        font-weight:normal;
        margin:1em 0;
        }   
    h2{            
        font-size:160%;
        }   
    h3{          
        font-size:140%;
        }
    h4{          
        font-size:120%;
        }

    a{
        text-decoration:none;
        color:#f30;
        }
    a:hover{
        color:#999;
        }           
    table, input, textarea, select, li{
        font:100% Trebuchet MS, Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
        line-height:160%;
        color:#333;
        }               
    p, blockquote, ul, ol, form{
        margin:1em 0;
        }
    blockquote{
        }
    img{
        border:none;
        }           
    hr{
        display:none;
        }   
    table{
        margin:1em 0;
        width:100%;
        border-collapse:collapse;
        }
    th, td{ 
        padding:2px 5px;
        }   
    th{ 
        text-align:left;
        }
    li{
        display:list-item;
        }

    #container{ 
        margin:0 auto;
        background:#fff;
        width:600px;
        padding:20px 40px;
        text-align:left;
        }

        #form1{
            margin:1em 0;
            padding-top:10px;
            background:url(../images/form/form_top.gif) no-repeat 0 0;
            }
        #form1 fieldset{
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            border:none;    
            float:left;
            display:inline;
            width:260px;
            margin-left:25px;
            }       
        #form1 legend{display:none;}    
        #form1 p{margin:.5em 0;}    
        #form1 label{display:block;}    
        #form1 input, #form1 textarea{      
            width:252px;
            border:1px solid #ddd;
            background:#fff url(../images/form/form_input.gif) repeat-x;
            padding:3px;
            }       
        #form1 textarea{
            height:125px;
            overflow:auto;
            }                   
        #form1 p.submit{
            clear:both;
            background:url(../images/form/form_bottom.gif) no-repeat 0 100%;
            padding:0 25px 20px 25px;
            margin:0;
            text-align:right;
            }   
        #form1 button{
            width:150px;
            height:37px;
            line-height:37px;       
            border:none;
            background:url(../images/form/form_button.gif) no-repeat 0 0;
            color:#fff;
            cursor:pointer;
            text-align:center;
            }

При нажатии на кнопку отправить вылезает следующая ошибка

Не указано имя!

"; $send_error = 1; } if (empty($email)) { echo "Не указан e-mail!

"; $send_error = 1; else { if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { echo "E-mail указан не верно!

"; $send_error = 1; } } if (empty($mess)) { echo "Сообщение не написано!

"; $send_error = 1; } else { if($send_error == 1) { echo "Вернуться к заполнению формы"; } else { $to = "mail@example.ru"; $subject = "Сообщение с сайта"; $message = "Имя пославшего: $name \n\nЭлектронный адрес: $email \n\nСообщение: $mess"; $headers = "Content-type: text/plain; charset = utf-8\r\n"; $headers .= "From: $name <$email>\r\n"; $send = mail ($to, $subject, $message, $headers); if ($send == 'true') { echo "Спасибо за отправку вашего сообщения!"; echo "Нажмите, чтобы вернуться на главную страницу"; } else { echo "Ошибка. Сообщение не отправлено!

"; } } } ?>
```

Comment: Ого, хоть бы ошибку процитировали. И поправьте оформление, кровь из глаз хлещет.

Comment: Скопируйте полный текст ошибки. У меня все нормально.

Comment: Вот простыня CSS - самое нужное, как же без неё... `mail()` ошибку возвращает, наверное? С локалхоста под windows?

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста синтаксис правильный?
И еще... я так понимаю при загрузки сайта на хостинг, отправлять сообщение на мой ящик будет сервер. А я тестирую конкретную форму у себя на ПК. Может нужно на ПК денвер установить? Спастбо

Comment: Читать и вникать: http://phpfaq.ru/debug На все ваши вопросы ответы там есть - что не работает и как это понять. Спрашивать "правильный ли у меня синтаксис" вообще не нужно, это нужно выяснять самостоятельно.

Comment: Да я все проверил и "обвникался" (уже пар из ушей валит), надеялся, что компитентный человек ткнет меня носом в ошибку(

Comment: Вы не читали этот текст. Иначе в голове бы отложилось хотя бы это:

>Получив сообщение об ошибке, вы можете его прочитать и исправить.
Если не справились - пишите на форум. При этом КОПИРУЙТЕ сообщение об ошибке,

Comment: комп**и**тентных людей небывает

Comment: а глаголы с частицей "не" пишутся раздельно

Comment: Собрал из интереса ваш пример. **Все работает как положено** (если не придираться к неверной html-разметке. Даже письмо уходит.   
Судя по куску **php-кода**, который вываливается в виде **html-кода**, вы накосячили с кавычками при выводе результата.  
А судя по тому коду, который вывалился в виде html (очевидно, что это часть **mail.php**), нам вы показываете один mail.php, а сами работаете с другим, потому что их окончания не совпадают.  
Разбейте свою простыню кода на блоки, соответствующие файлам. Читать невозможно же...

Comment: А еще можно не париться и создать форму обратной связи в конструкторе форм https://www.testograf.ru/ru/
Подробнее о том, как создать форму обратной связи https://www.testograf.ru/ru/blog/forma-obratnoj-svyazi.html

Comment: Думаю вот тут проще и без перезагрузки страницы: http://progme.ru/php/forma-obratnoj-svyazi-na-php-i-ajax/

Answer (score 1):

Вывод ошибки, который вы указали, не может вывести вышеуказанный обработчик.

"$send_error = 1; " Вообще не вижу этого в коде.

Сюдя по тому же выводу конструкции типа exit, die и прочее не используются.

```
<telepatemode> Проверьте расстановку ковычек. </telepatemode>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы в проверках EXIT на DIE() замените и по ходу все заработает.
т.к. по логике вы выдаете ошибку (отсутствие данных) и продолжаете выполнение скрипта.

Comment: Еще один. Вы знаете, в чем отличие exit от die?